# new constructor and function

Tags: java

I am new to java programming and I have seen this kind of classes. I guess that it's a faster way to write *new* `A`, `A.funct()` but I am not sure.Can anyone tell me that am I right or it's something else?

```
class A
{

     public void funct()
     {
          //something here
     }

     public static void main(String args[])
     {
          new A.funct();//What happends here
          // it's exactly the same thing with new A(), A.funct ?
     }
}
```

Comment: This is just another way to get a compile error (A.funct cannot be resolved to a type). I think it should be: new A().funct();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've actually seen

```
new A().funct();
```

and yes, it's the same as

```
A a = new A();
a.funct();
```

Since you are dereferencing the local variable `a` only once, it doesn't really need to be declared.

Answer (score 3):

`new A.funct();//What happends here`

You're trying to create a new `Object`, so you need to call the `Constructor`.

```
new A().funct();
// Assuming class A is either using the default constructor or has a no param constructor.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's like writing:

```
A myObj = new A();
myObj.funct();
```